# C++ random number generator for different opportunities

Tags: c++

Help with this C++ code
C++I want to generate a random number for each opportunity. How can I do this? because if it is inside the "do" in the other "if" it is not definded.

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
int guess = 20;
int opportunity=1;
srand((unsigned)time(0));
int random_integer=(rand()%30)+1;
do
{
  
    cout<<"Number entered: "<<random_integer<<endl;
    if(random_integer > guess)
      cout<<"Number to high"<<endl;
    else
      if(random_integer < guess)
       cout<<"Number to low"<<endl;
      else
       cout<<"This was the number to guess"<<endl;
    opportunity++;
    
}while((random_integer != guess)&&(opportunity <= 3));

if(random_integer == guess)
 cout<<"Yes you guessed right"<<" after "<<opportunity- 
1<< " opportunity "<<endl;
else
 cout<<"The number to guess was: "<<guess<<endl;
  cout<<"You can try again if you want"<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do this the same way you would declare a variable at the beginning of the function, but only initialize it somewhere later in the function.

Comment: Why are you using `srand`/`rand` in modern C++? Why not use the (much better) facilities in the `random` library: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random ?

Comment: its a university class. I use what they teach and what they ask for. Cant use any other stuff that they haven't teached yet.

Comment: That describes a huge problem with the teaching of programming in general. Often the teacher will not teach modern usages of a programming language because the lesson plan was laid out in the 1960s for a completely different language. This results in a very bumpy interface between school and professional life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When srand() is seeded with time(NULL) it will generate a random number based on the time of the clock of the computer. So, if you initialize the variable randowm_integer with rand() the function is only called once. but, if you place the random_integer = (rand() % 30) + 1; inside of the do-while loop, it will be called multiple times-- making a different number every iteration.

```
int guess = 20;
int opportunity = 1;
srand(time(NULL));
int random_integer =0;
do
{

    random_integer = (rand() % 30) + 1;// random_integer is reassigned every loop. 
    cout << "Number entered: " << random_integer << endl;
    if (random_integer > guess)
        cout << "Number to high" << endl;
    else
        if (random_integer < guess)
            cout << "Number to low" << endl;
        else
            cout << "This was the number to guess" << endl;
    opportunity++;

} while ((random_integer != guess) && (opportunity <= 3));
```

Comment: Thanks that solved. Another question if I can. If I wanted to leave the computer to make as many guesses as it needed until it guesses the random number. How may I do that? i know I have to delete the (opportunity<=3) but what else can I do? "Sorry I am starting to learn this and its for a university class"

Comment: If you wanted to have the guess random but the random_integer stays the same. Move the random_integer outside the do-while and place the guess inside the do-while loop. like this:  if (random_integer != guess) guess = (rand() % 30) + 1;